# bootstrap: table goes behind the borders

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make table inside a well inside a modal. Here's a piece of code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <form class="well form-inline">
        <label><h5>rtu</h5></label>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>mid</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>inverce</th>
                <th>mbaddr</th>
                <th>din_reg_offset</th>
                <th>din_type</th>
                <th>dout_reg_offset</th>
                <th>dout_type</th>
                <th>ain_reg_offset</th>
                <th>ain_type</th>
                <th>aout_reg_offset</th>
                <th>aout_type</th>
                <th>float_type</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="mid"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="type"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="inverce"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="mbaddr"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="din_reg_offset"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="din_type"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="dout_reg_offset"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="dout_type"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="ain_reg_offset"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="ain_type"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="aout_reg_offset"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="aout_type"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="float_type"></td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </form>
</form>
```

But table didn't fit into well's borders. Like this:
[image]

But I want something like this:
[image]
What did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your table markup is incorrect. It should follow this format.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Month</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

(From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp)

Comment: Are you doing anything in CSS to make the `input type="text"` elements smaller than the Bootstrap default size?

Comment: No. I tried to set something like `class="span4"` to input, but as I understand it refers to whole page, not a modal.

Comment: You can still use 'span4' - unless you are using the responsive stylesheet it gives a pixel (rather than percentage) width. (Although I suspect a smaller span will be required.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class="input-mini"` or `class="input-small"` on your inputs to make them smaller. But you table will always have a fixed min-width with your inputs in it, and the `well` will resize with the content around it. You may still end up with issues in small browser windows.